# Nested conditional operator / mux syntax

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to output a tone to a speaker via a set of pushbuttons. I managed to make it work with a case statement but am having trouble trying translating that to a mux, as case statements within always_ff are not allowed according my guidelines. I keep getting an error for Procedural continuous assignment error and I'm not sure on the meaning of that

My code is as follows

```
module test
    (
    input logic clk50,
    input logic [1:0] x,
    output logic speaker
    );

    logic [15:0] count;
    always_ff @ (posedge clk50)
    
    assign count = x[1] ? (x[0] ? {count == 0 ? 17857 : count-1} : {count == 0? 50000 : count-1}):
                                 (x[0] ? {count == 0 ? 50000 : count-1} : 0 );
    

    //begin
    //case (x)
    
        //2'b10: count = count == 0? 50000: count-1;
        //2'b01: count = count == 0? 50000: count-1;
        //2'b00: count = count == 0? 17857: count-1;
        
    //endcase
    //end
    
    always_ff @ (posedge clk50)
    speaker = count == 0? ~speaker:speaker;
    
        
endmodule
```

Comment: Sorry I meant I made the circuit work with a case statement, syntax wise. But project parameter wise, I am not allowed to use case or if statements within an always_ff block. Therefore I have to convert the case statement to a mux or something else in order to fulfill the requirements

Answer (score 0):

A procedural continuous assignment is an `assign` statement inside an `always` block, `initial` block, or other procedural block. They have limited if any support synthesis support. Most simulators support this feature, however the SystemVerilog LRM has been warning about deprecating the feature since IEEE1800-2005 (you can read about the explanation in [IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § C.4.2).

Once a procedural block reaches the `assign` statement, the line will be treated as a continuous assignment until a different `assign` or `deassign` on the same variable is executed. In your case `count` will be updated on any change of `x` or `count` (asynchronous feedback loop). It will consider `clk50` for its first posedge only to trigger the procedural continuous assignment. After that time the clock is ignored

You should avoid using `assign` (and `deassign`) inside procedural code. You should also use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) when assigning synchronous logic to avoid simulation race conditions. Change your assignment to `count` to the follow to get the desired behavior:

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk50)
  count <= x[1] ? (x[0] ? {count == 0 ? 17857 : count-1} :
                          {count == 0 ? 50000 : count-1}):
                  (x[0] ? {count == 0 ? 50000 : count-1} : 0 );
```

References and examples of procedural continuous assignment in the latest SystemVerilog RLM [IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html):

- § 10.6.1 *The assign and deassign procedural statements*
- § C.4 *Constructs identified for deprecation*
- § C.4.2 *Procedural assign and deassign statements*

Answer (score -1):

```
module test(
  input  logic       clk50,
  input  logic [1:0] x,
  output logic       speaker
);
  logic [15:0] count;

  always_ff @ (posedge clk50)begin
    speaker <= (count == 0) ? ~speaker : speaker;
    count   <= ((x == 2'b01)||(x == 2'b10)) ? ((count == 0) ? 50000 : count-1) :
                (x == 2'b00)                ? ((count == 0) ? 17857 : count-1) :
                                                count;
  end
endmodule
```